# How can i wait for API callback to completely render a component?

Tags: arrays, laravel, api, object, vue.js

I get a request from an API and then assign the data into a property called `source` in the `created` method. Now facing some problem in render function to assign the some data from `source` to they properties `participants` before the component is completely created

The `source` property has its after the component is completely rendered but no data in `participants`

This is `API Resource`

```
return [
          'id' => $this->id,
          'user_id' => $this->user_id,
          'participants' => [
              'id' => $this->user_id,
              'name' => $this->user->name,
              'imageUrl' => 'https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/37018832?s=200&v=4'
          ],
          'body' =>[
              'type' => 'text', 
              'author' => $this->user == auth()->user() ? "me" : $this->user->name,
              'data' => ['text' => $this->body],
          ],
          'created_at' => $this->created_at->diffForHumans(),
      ];
```

This is my element tag `<beautiful-chat>`

```
<beautiful-chat 
  :participants="participants" 
  :messageList="messageList"
  v-if=" this.source.length > 0 "
/>
```

This is render function

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      source: {},
      room_id: ChatRoom.id(),
      participants:[],
      messageList: [],
    };
  },
  created(){
      axios.get(`/api/room/${this.room_id}/message`)
        .then(res => this.source = res.data.data);

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.source, child => {
        const parti = Object.keys(child.participants).map(i => child.participants[i])

        this.participants.push({'id': parti[0], 'name' : parti[1], 'imageUrl' : parti[2]});

        const message = Object.keys(child.body).map(i => child.body[i])

        this.messageList.push({'type': message[0], 'author' : message[1], 'data' :message[2] });

    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Where can i get the data from source to put them inside my properties instead of `created` method

Comment: Is the `res.data.data` an `array` or an `object` ?

Comment: it is an object, i will update question for `API` resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first make the `source=null`

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      source: null,
      room_id: ChatRoom.id(),
      participants:[],
      messageList: [],
    };
  },
  created(){
    axios.get(`/api/room/${this.room_id}/message`)
      .then(res => {
        let source = res.data.data
        // Array.prototype.forEach.call(source, child => {
        //   const parti = Object.keys(child.participants).map(i => child.participants[i])
        //   this.participants.push({'id': parti[0], 'name' : parti[1], 'imageUrl' : parti[2]});
        //   const message = Object.keys(child.body).map(i => child.body[i])
        //   this.messageList.push({'type': message[0], 'author' : message[1], 'data' :message[2] });
        // });
        
        // a better way:
        this.participants = [source.participants]
        this.messageList = [source.body]
        
        this.source = source
      });
  }
};
```

And in template:

```html
<beautiful-chat 
  :participants="participants" 
  :messageList="messageList"
  v-if="source"
/>
```

Also you can use [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).